# Error al desplegar aplicación web mediante servidor de aplicaciones Liberty en java

Tags: java, nodejs, eclipse, jsf

Hola amigos buenas tardes,

Estoy intentando desplegar una aplicación web pero al momento de levantarlo me genera el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualizado:
Agrego lo que tiene mi web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>jeveris-web</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Localizacion del fichero de configuracion de Spring.Utilizado por el listener de Spring.</description>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/app/core/conf/core-cfg.xml,/WEB-INF/app/core/conf/spring-security-cfg.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/core/facelets/jeveris.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.VIEW_HANDLERS</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.handleViewExpiredOnClient</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ADD_RESOURCE_CLASS</param-name>
        <param-value>org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.DefaultAddResource</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.CHECK_EXTENSIONS_FILTER</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>This param is needed to avoid MYFACES-1786 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-1786)</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.secret</param-name>
        <param-value>NzY1NDMyMTA=</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Parametro especifico de JBoss que corrige alguna
            incompatibilidad JBoss-MyFaces 1.2. Si esta activo, se
            utiliza MyFaces en lugar de Sun RI</description>
        <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
        <param-value>j-telcel</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>createTempFiles</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>maxRequestSize</param-name>
            <param-value>1000000000</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <description>Listener que inicializa Spring.</description>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <description>This listener is used to enabled spring session and request scopes</description>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>3</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>detail</param-name>
            <param-value>3</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <description>Configuration Manager Servlet</description>
        <display-name>ConfigManagerServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>ConfigManagerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.jeveris.pl.configuration.control.ConfigManagerServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <description>LogoutServlet</description>
        <display-name>LogoutServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.jeveris.pl.core.LogoutServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <description>DescargafileServlet</description>
        <display-name>DescargafileServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>DescargafileServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>mx.everis.comun.util.DescargarArchivoServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DescargafileServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/DescargafileServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ConfigManagerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ConfigManagerServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/LogoutServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/core/error/500.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Agrego el Pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- <parent> <groupId>mx.telecom.telcel</groupId> <artifactId>j-everis-telcel</artifactId> 
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath> 
        </parent> -->
    <groupId>mx.telecom.telcel</groupId>
    <artifactId>MetodosDePago</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MetodosDePago</name>
    <description>Proyecto web Metodos de Pago</description>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <!-- Construcion de archivo war para equipo local -->
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>local</envClassifier>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <finalName>${name}</finalName>
                <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.6</source>
                            <target>1.6</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.8</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <ajdtVersion>none</ajdtVersion>
                            <wtpmanifest>true</wtpmanifest>
                            <wtpapplicationxml>true</wtpapplicationxml>
                            <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                            <additionalProjectFacets>
                                <jst.web>2.5</jst.web>
                                <java>1.6</java>
                                <jst.jsf>1.2</jst.jsf>
                                <wst.jsdt.web>1.0</wst.jsdt.web>
                            </additionalProjectFacets>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>produccion</id>
            <!-- Constrcuccion del war/ear sin archivos estaticos -->
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>produccion</envClassifier>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <finalName>${name}</finalName>
                <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.6</source>
                            <target>1.6</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <warName>MetodosDePago</warName>
                            <packagingExcludes>core/js/,core/skins/,core/static/</packagingExcludes>
                            <webResources>
                                <resource>
                                    <targetPath>WEB-INF/app/core/conf</targetPath>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources-produccion</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>hibernate-connection-cfg.xml</include>
                                        <include>acegi-config.xml</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <targetPath>WEB-INF/app/core/conf</targetPath>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/app/core/conf</directory>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>hibernate-connection-cfg.xml</exclude>
                                        <exclude>acegi-config.xml</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </resource>
                            </webResources>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jeveris</groupId>
            <artifactId>j-everis-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jeveris</groupId>
            <artifactId>j-everis-abm</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2-TELCEL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jeveris</groupId>
            <artifactId>j-everis-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2-TELCEL</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jeveris</groupId>
            <artifactId>j-everis-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2-TELCEL</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jeveris</groupId>
            <artifactId>j-everis-logging</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2-TELCEL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core-tiger</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-impl</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-impl-jsf2</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-attrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bouncycastle-jce-jdk13</artifactId>
            <version>112</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.1_3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.14</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-el</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-el</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <!-- Or whatever version, as long as it's fixed -->
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.GA</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>javax.faces</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>1.2_15</version> -->
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>javax.faces</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>1.2_15</version> -->
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <!-- <scope>compile</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrpc</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
            <artifactId>oscache</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomahawk</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-el</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-el</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>concurrent</groupId>
            <artifactId>concurrent</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>javax.mail</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>mail</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>1.4.4</version> -->
        <!-- <scope>runtime</scope> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.ga</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hibernate3</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oro</groupId>
            <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>db2java_BCK2</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2java_BCK2.jar</artifactId>
            <version>LAST</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/db2java_BCK2.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>db2java</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2java.jar</artifactId>
            <version>LAST</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/db2java.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>db2jcc_javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc_javax.jar</artifactId>
            <version>LAST</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/db2jcc_javax.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>db2jcc_license_cisuz</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar</artifactId>
            <version>LAST</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>db2jcc_license_cu</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cu.jar</artifactId>
            <version>LAST</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/db2jcc_license_cu.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>db2jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc.jar</artifactId>
            <version>LAST</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/db2jcc.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources-produccion</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

He estado buscando información acerca de este error pero no me deja avanzar, a que se deberá que ocurra este error? Espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, la aplicación está hecha con tecnologías node js, java y jsf.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando spring agrega el ContextLoaderListener en tu web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Hola @Frezco, muchas gracias, acabo de actualizar mi pregunta anexando mi web.xml, el listener ya lo tengo en el archivo y aun así sigue marcando error :(

Comment: Podrías poner todo el error completo, así como las versiones de jsf, spring o java

Comment: Hola Frezno, buenos dias, acabo de agregar mi pom.xml ya que igual ahí vendrían las versiones que se están usando, espero y se logre entender, intenté poner el error pero no me dejó la pagina por eso los coloqué en imagen muchas gracias

Comment: Tu archivo ConfigManagerServlet parece que no esta disponible en el acceso de la aplicación